# UE4 how to restrict when On component Hit registers a collision

Tags: game-engine, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have a rather simple setup. I am trying to register collision when a cube is hit by a projectile(sphere). I am using the gun from the first person template in UE4 and spawn a cube with a simple ai that follows the player. I am using the On Component Hit node to register when the cube has been hit by a projectile. However, this has the side effect that the cube will explode whenever it comes in contact with anything eg. the player's gun. I am trying to find a way to restrict the event call to only register when the cube is hit with the projectile. should I use a different node or should I use the normal impulse to register the collision? Below is a picture of the blueprint that handles despawning the enemy, any help is appreciated. I did some research and couldn't find anything on this topic though if this is a common question then a link to a thread would be much appreciated :-)

[Blueprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACZmW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is happening because there is no limitation on what is considered a hit. Your player collision hitting the static mesh will activate the event and it will destroy itself. Rifle touching the cube would also activate it.

You need to check if the other actor is a bullet or whatever you want the cause of it's destruction to be. There are many ways to do this, but the simplest one to me is to cast to your projectile class. If the cast is successful it will destroy the object. If it's not, nothing will happen because the cast failed.

[bullet_collision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoVAm.png)

If you have multiple different kinds of bullets, create a base bullet class and cast the base. This way, it will always succeed if any of the bullets inherit from the base class.